# OkHttp - keep getting the error: "content-type of request should be application/json"

Tags: okhttp

Why do I get this error "content-type of request should be application/json", because I encoded it application/json?
How to correct it?
In Postman the request is working fine.

```
int id = 208;
MediaType JsonType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
String jsonBody = "{\"params\":[\"wandelnet\"," + id + "]}";
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(jsonBody, JsonType);
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url( "https://wandelnet.api.routemaker.nl/routemaker/getPublishedRoute")
        .post(body)
        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
        .addHeader( "Accept", "application/json")
        .build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

The result is:

> {"result":null,"error":{"code":"sherpaBadRequest","message":"content-type
> of request should be application/json"}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating the request body from bytes, not from a string:

```
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(jsonBody.getBytes(“UTF-8”), JsonType);
```

OkHttp automatically adds a charset when it does string encoding, and we need to prevent this here.

You’ll also want to omit the Content-Type header in your request builder.

Answer (score 1):

While creating the body of the request you should write the type of the body first and afterwards, you should add body content. So, it should look like this:

```
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JsonType, jsonBody);
```

Try this out.